# How to remove an inner section from a path bounded section?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I  have the following image in Illustrator:

[image]

Inside the wheel I want to put a white hole. How? Wheel is bounded by path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a circle.

Select the circle and the cog.

Choose `Object > Compound Path > Make`